ESLint complains about type declaration
I declared a custom type in the codebase, like this:
/**
 * SearchBoxOption Type
 */
export declare type SearchBoxOption = {
  /**
   * A key, shall be unique for all entries put into the SearchBox component.
   * When using ObjectId from a database, it should be put here.
   */
  key: string,

  /**
   * Option type, allows to provide correct icon. The list of types is used
   * to return data in the SearchRequestCallBackFunction.
   */
  type: 'category' | 'tag',

  /**
   * String used to be displayed.
   */
  name: string
}

Yet it complains that this type is undefined:

How is this possible, since I'm just declaring the type?

Because you're using the JS no-undef, so you haven't correctly configured ESLint for TypeScript.
